# Logon failed to localhost using a domain name via remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, localhost

I want to connect to localhost via remote desktop, the OS is Windows server 2008 r2.

I can connect successfully using 127.0.0.1,::1,localhost and the IP address in the network.

But when I tried to connect using the domain name points to it's IP address in the network, I encountered an error says "Your credentials did not work".

I have checked the log:

```
Event Id: 4625
Failure Information:
Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
Status:         0xc000006d
Sub Status:     0x0
```

And following an answer at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14983471-b25a-4bb6-81e0-aa63bed9b4ac/event-id-4625-null-sid-error?forum=winserver8gen , I uninstalled KB3002657. However, the problem persists. Then I have no idea about how to solve it.